# Ebook BULK Rename Title,Author

Tags: ebooks

i how **2500** *ebooks* my system rename this Book **Title,Author**
how do help you ?
**Calibre** All ready use any one Alternative
my system **os** windows 7.

Comment: Where do you expect to get the title & author data from, (possibly the meta data)? What ebook format(s) do you have?

Comment: pdf and epup format my books